# Postman's restsharp code snippet not working in winforms c#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, web-services, restsharp

I have to send two parameters to a remote web service: **firmaNo** and **irsaliyeData**. firmaNo is **numeric** and irsaliyeData is a **json object**. I have already tried it with Postman and it worked without any problem. But i have to do it with a c# desktop application for my company.

I entered paramaters manually and send them to web service with Postman, server returned with a valid value. Postman generated the codes(c#-RestSharp) below:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://remoteserver.com/webservice");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"firmaNo\"\r\n\r\n2000007\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"irsaliyeData\"\r\n\r\n{   \"rampaNoktasi\": 21,   \"dosyaTarihi\": \"16.12.2016 17:37\"   }\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

But when I copy and paste this code to my c# winform application's button click event handler, server always returns Time Out error.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://remoteserver.com/webservice");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"firmaNo\"\r\n\r\n2000007\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"irsaliyeData\"\r\n\r\n" + jsonstring + "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
lbl_result.Text = response.Content + response.ErrorMessage;
```

Do I have to add some code to the current cs file or app.config file. I am stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may or may not assist you, but when I was dealing with a similar issue I had to add a charset to the "Content-Type" for the server to recognize the exchange, `"ContentType","application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"`

Comment: @vipersassassin thanks for the quick reply, I tried to change content-type to application/json but I got time out again :/

Comment: Well the only thing that seems to be different is the boundary id and the jsonstring. I would try to set the jsonstring to the same as the first example and also use the same boundary and make that work. If that wont work when you know it is not the code that is the problem. Otherwise just replace one piece at a time. Start with changing the boundary and then the jsonstring to another value. Then you know where the problem lies.

Comment: Are you running the first code part (that works) in the same project as the non working code?

Comment: @FSDaniel thank you for the quick reply, sorry I forgot to say that I used Postman chrome extension to get the first code. When I post parameters with postman, web service returns a valid value, but when I do it with my winform application it is time out. That's why I said first code is working.

Comment: @FSDaniel I tried exactly the same code(generated from Postman) with my winform application and again I got time out from server :/

Comment: Try stripping everything out of your code in WinForms and using a blank template to start from (i.e. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) then work forward from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using WebClient method instead of RestSharp.

Thanks to everyone for help.